# ubuntu 16.04 bluetooth mx5000 logitech keyboard mouse NOT working

Tags: keyboard, 16.04, bluetooth, logitech

I just installed ubuntu 16.04 using a cable keyboard and mouse because my  mx5000 logitech bluetooth keyboard and mouse was not working during the instalation .

After installation completed and got 1rst update I plugged in the logitech MX5000 combo and  was still not working .
on `lsusb` I got:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8002 Intel Corp. Bus 002 Device 001: ID  
   1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
 Bus 001 Device 002: ID       8087:800a Intel Corp. Bus 001 Device
   001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux       Foundation 2.0 root hub
 Bus 004 Device 002: ID 045b:0210 Hitachi, Ltd
 Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
 Bus 003 Device 007: ID 046d:c709 Logitech, Inc. BT Mini-Receiver (HCI
   mode)
 Bus 003 Device 006: ID 046d:0b02 Logitech, Inc. C-UV35      
   [Bluetooth Mini-Receiver] (HID proxy mode)
 Bus 003 Device 004: ID       045b:0209 Hitachi, Ltd 
 Bus 003 Device 003: ID 045e:00f7 Microsoft Corp. LifeCam VX-1000
 Bus 003 Device 002: ID 03f0:0b2a   Hewlett-Packard Bus 003 Device
   005: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp.
 Bus 003     Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Still, keyboard would not syncronize, or become visible, so as the mouse.
On different forums I found that  keeping the small red button on the usb stick ....and then inserting it in usb , keeping the button pressed for 3-5 more seconds should fix the problem , changing from HCI mode. it did not worked for me !

then a user from a romanian ubuntu forum  named " Bula20 " was kind enough to help and guide me . here is the solution

SOLUTION:

from folder `/lib/udev/rules.d/` copy the file called `97-hid2hci.rules`  to your desktop for example . then  open the file and edit it. where you see `#Logitech devices`  right under you should have 2 lines like :

```
KERNEL=="hiddev*",ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d",ATTRS{idProduct}=="c70[345abce]|c71[3bc]", \
  RUN+="hid2hci --method=logitech-hid --devpath=%p"
```

just replaced thoose 2 lines with :

```
 KERNEL=="hiddev*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c709 |
   0b02", \
 RUN+="hid2hci --method=logitech-hid --devpath=%p     "
```

then save the file and  copy this file to `/etc/udev/rules.d` folder ( mine was empty ) . to be able to save the file there you should have root privilege , so do it by opening a terminal and use command line :

`cp -vi source-file‘s--path destination’s-path`

or

```
cp -R source-file‘s--path destination’s-path
```

in my case ( and your case ) command line in terminal should be : 
`cp -vi /home/desktop/Desktop/97-hid2hci.rules /etc/udev/rules.d`

or

`cp -R /home/desktop/Desktop/97-hid2hci.rules /etc/udev/rules.d`

now , if you go in `/etc/udev/rules.d`   you should be able too see the file `97-hid2hci.rules`   there .

NEXT step is to execute in terminal this: `sudo update-initramfs -u`  let it do the job, the reboot.

Logitech MX5000 combo keyboard and mouse on bluetooth will work :)

Comment: after reboot , lsusb lookes like this : lsusb
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 046d:c70a Logitech, Inc. MX5000 Cordless Desktop
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 046d:c70e Logitech, Inc. MX1000 Bluetooth Laser Mouse
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 046d:0b02 Logitech, Inc. C-UV35 [Bluetooth Mini-Receiver] (HID proxy mode)

Comment: This solution worked great for my MX5500 combo mouse and keyboard on Ubuntu 18.04 so I can confirm it's still a good solution for Logitech devices and newer versions of Ubuntu.  Thank you!

Comment: For Logitech MX Vertical and Ubuntu 18.04, it didn't work.