# Logitech bluetooth keyboard and mouse: not discoverable in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, mouse, bluetooth, logitech

I am unable to discover my Logitech MX Master mouse and Logitech G613 keyboard in my bluetooth device manager. I have successfully connected to other bluetooth devices, but have had no success with my logitech devices. I am able to see both my mouse and keyboard from other bluetooth enabled devices, however. I can also connect both devices using their respective usb dongles, though I would prefer to leverage their bluetooth capabilities.

My setup: Lenovo Thinkpad X1C7 running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS with kernel 5.3.0-24-generic.

Any suggestions on what the issue could be?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I was hoping the method posted here would provide a solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/774587/ubuntu-16-04-bluetooth-mx5000-logitech-keyboard-mouse-not-working

Unfortunately, the issue persists. Any other ideas would be appreciated.